# Is it possible to have an unsigned ByteBuffer in java?

Tags: java

Subject says it all.  I'm working with OpenGL and OpenCL and would make life easier if I could just use an unsigned ByteBuffer to store data.

Answer (score 73):

unsigned ByteBuffer example:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class test {
    public static short getUnsignedByte(ByteBuffer bb) {
        return ((short) (bb.get() & 0xff));
    }

    public static void putUnsignedByte(ByteBuffer bb, int value) {
        bb.put((byte) (value & 0xff));
    }

    public static short getUnsignedByte(ByteBuffer bb, int position) {
        return ((short) (bb.get(position) & (short) 0xff));
    }

    public static void putUnsignedByte(ByteBuffer bb, int position, int value) {
        bb.put(position, (byte) (value & 0xff));
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------

    public static int getUnsignedShort(ByteBuffer bb) {
        return (bb.getShort() & 0xffff);
    }

    public static void putUnsignedShort(ByteBuffer bb, int value) {
        bb.putShort((short) (value & 0xffff));
    }

    public static int getUnsignedShort(ByteBuffer bb, int position) {
        return (bb.getShort(position) & 0xffff);
    }

    public static void putUnsignedShort(ByteBuffer bb, int position, int value) {
        bb.putShort(position, (short) (value & 0xffff));
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------

    public static long getUnsignedInt(ByteBuffer bb) {
        return ((long) bb.getInt() & 0xffffffffL);
    }

    public static void putUnsignedInt(ByteBuffer bb, long value) {
        bb.putInt((int) (value & 0xffffffffL));
    }

    public static long getUnsignedInt(ByteBuffer bb, int position) {
        return ((long) bb.getInt(position) & 0xffffffffL);
    }

    public static void putUnsignedInt(ByteBuffer bb, int position, long value) {
        bb.putInt(position, (int) (value & 0xffffffffL));
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(20);

        buffer.clear();
        test.putUnsignedByte(buffer, 255);
        test.putUnsignedByte(buffer, 128);
        test.putUnsignedShort(buffer, 0xcafe);
        test.putUnsignedInt(buffer, 0xcafebabe);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            System.out.println("" + i + ": "
                    + Integer.toHexString((int) getUnsignedByte(buffer, i)));
        }

        System.out.println("2: "
                + Integer.toHexString(getUnsignedShort(buffer, 2)));
        System.out.println("4: " + Long.toHexString(getUnsignedInt(buffer, 4)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

how about this
Short.toUnsignedInt(buffer.getShort());

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't support unsigned types. The typical solution is to go to the next biggest type (in your case: short), and just mask it so you only use the lower 'n' (in your case 8) bits.

... but that kind of breaks when you try to apply to buffers :-(

Answer (score -4):

It's not a problem of `ByteBuffer` - even if it was *unsigned* - every byte that you read from it will be signed, just because `byte` is signed and we can't change that.

Comment: Rubbish. Bytes are bytes. That they're treated as signed only matters when sign extending or using them as numeric values. All you need to do is read the bytes in to a number that can hold more bytes than the one you want to have "unsigned" (`int` for `short`s, `long` for `int`s, `BigInteger` for `long`s, etc).

Comment: Writing an own utility method doing & 0xff is rubbish.

Comment: At last I found the nice class in guava doing exactly what I want http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteArrayDataInput.html#readUnsignedByte%28%29

Comment: You can't set the endianness with the guava one.