# Java object to UDP byte[]

Tags: java, udp, bytebuffer

I'm trying to create a UDP client server. I am already able to read the messages by doing the following:

My incoming message is BIG_ENDIAN and the structure is this:

```
UINT8  type;           
UINT8  flags;              
UINT16 len;                
UINT32 sequenceN;          
UINT16 startIdx;         
UINT16 endIdx;
```

The corresponding Java objects are:

```
short type;
short flags;
int len;
long sequenceN;
int startIdx;
int endIdx;
```

To convert from UDP to Java I use the following:

```
typeArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(msg, 0, 1);
type = Util.reassembleShort(typeArray);
flagsArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(msg, 1, 2);
flags = Util.reassembleShort(flagsArray);
lenArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(msg, 2, 4);
len = Util.reassembleInt(lenArray);
seqArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(msg, 4, 8);
sequenceN = Util.reassembleLong(seqArray);
startArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(msg, 8, 10);
startIdx = Util.reassembleInt(startArray);
endArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(msg, 10, 12);
endIdx = Util.reassembleInt(endArray);
```

To reassemble byte array portions into Java objects I use the following (AKA the calls to Util.reassemble* above):

Short

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(input);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
short result = ((short) (buffer.get() & 0xff));
```

Long

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(input);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
long result = ((long) buffer.getInt() & 0xffffffffL);
```

Int

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(input);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
int result = (buffer.getShort() & 0xffff);
```

String

```
String result = new String(removeStringGarbage(input), Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
```

This works great. My question is... how do I do the reverse and get the objects into a correctly sized bytebuffer to send back on UDP?

Comment: "To convert from UDP to Java I use the following"--why not just read out of a `ByteBuffer` instead? Cheaper and more readable.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention the variable "msg" is the incoming bytebuffer.

Comment: A byte buffer or a `ByteBuffer`? In the latter case, you can just `getShort()` or whatever.

Comment: Ahh. My bad it is read in as a byte array. * byte[] data = incoming.getData();
         * String s = new String(data, 0, incoming.getLength());

Comment: @Tacitus86 Why? You don't need to convert it to a String. Just use `readShort()` etc, ... And `putShort()` and friends when writing. You're making a mountain out of a molehill.

Comment: Would I be able to read the entire byte array (which contains all the source values clumped together) into a bytebuffer and then readShort(), readShort(), readLong(), etc? Also would I be able to do the bit masking to change from unsigned to signed after and also deal with byte order?

Comment: Also I tried going this route for changing the java into bytes to send back on UDP in the following format 
`ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(DataAdapterFB1.HEADER_SIZE);
        buffer.order(java.nio.ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        buffer.putShort(type);
        buffer.putShort(flags);
        buffer.putInt(len);
        buffer.putLong(sequenceN);
        buffer.putInt(startIdx);
       buffer.putInt(endIdx);
 
        return buffer.array();` And it didn't work. All size my print statements were horribly off and I ran out of space in the byte buffer.

Comment: I thought it was due to the java object size (ie long in java being 8 byte vs long in the system i'm getting data from being  4 byte - uint32) which is another reason i couldn't just use get/put.

Comment: You should mask your data as appropriate, when doing putX(), to map it to the unsigned type (please see my updated answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you must follow a pre-existing on-the-wire binary format precisely, give "Kaitai Struct" (http://kaitai.io/) a try.

If you can afford to change you serialization format (i.e. you are in control of it), take a look at the "Protocol Buffers": https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial

In both cases, using a pre-existing library, to describe you binary protocol declaratively, will save you a great deal of time and effort,
and will normally result in a more robust code (as code generators can handle broken data better and never make typos).

And with "Protocol Buffers" you also get extensibility, i.e. you can evolve your protocol while preserving backward compatibility.

If you still want to serialize/deserialize your data manually,
just use the *ByteBuffer's* *putX* methods as follows:

```
 buffer.put((byte)(type & 0xFF));
 buffer.put((byte)(flags & 0xFF));
 buffer.putShort((short)(len & 0xFFFF));
 buffer.putInt((int)(sequenceN & 0xFFFFFFFF));
 buffer.putShort((short)(startIdx & 0xFFFF));
 buffer.putShort((short)(endIdx & 0xFFFF));
```

Put operation type should match your binary field size (i.e. put() for UINT8, putShort for UINT16, putInt for UINT32...), and you must apply a proper mask to it (i.e. 0xFF for short, 0xFFFF for int e.t.c.)

Comment: He *is* following an existing wire protocol precisely. It is specified in the question.

Comment: Yep you are probably correct on that (I was first confused by the "client server" and implied that OP is in control of on the wire encoding).
I've restructured my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks zeppelin. Just need to figure out how to convert (size down). I had to increase the size going from uint* to java object. So now i need to go Short -> uint8, Int -> uint16, long -> uint32. Any ideas?

Comment: >So now i need to go Short -> uint8, Int -> uint16, long -> uint32. Any >ideas? –

You just mask you wider type, as appropriate and then cast it down to a shorter type like that: buffer.put((byte)(type & 0xFF)); ("type" is "short" here)

That might seem a bit counterintuitive at first, but that is how it works.

You can also see this post for a more elaborate example:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883472/is-it-possible-to-have-an-unsigned-bytebuffer-in-java/9883582#9883582

Comment: Thanks everyone! Zeppelin, if you remove protocol buffers from your original answer, I can mark that as the answer.